# Java - How can I do an innerjoin between 2 indexes in elastic search? Lookup data in index B based on data from index A

Tags: java, lucene, elasticsearch

I have created 2 indexes in elasticsearch. There is a parent child relationship inherent in the data of the indexes. How can I join based on a column in elasticsearch in a search query?

Comment: Please post your current mapping and I don't think joins work with elasticsearch. Let us know what actually is your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do it using the Java interface, but I think you probably want the `terms` filter lookup - a great blog post detailing benefits and usage: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/terms-filter-lookup/